# Can't get HTTPS to work with grunt connect and livereload settings

Tags: ssl, gruntjs, connect, livereload, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm having a hard time trying to get all this to work so I can develop locally under an SSL cert.

I have all three required files sitting in the project root directory and I've tried different sets of options in different places but I can't seem to wrap my head around where all these settings need to go with the Gruntfile I have currently.

I used the `yeoman` angular generator to create my project so it puts things in some different places from what I can see comparing it to tutorials and such online so following someone else's instructions isn't getting me anywhere.

My Gruntfile looks like this...

```
// Generated on 2016-07-16 using generator-angular 0.15.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
    googlefonts: 'grunt-google-fonts',
    aws_s3: 'grunt-aws-s3',
    realFavicon: 'grunt-real-favicon'
  });

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'newer:jscs:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'newer:jscs:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass:dev','autoprefixer:dev']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                connect.static('./app/styles')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par
    jscs: {
      options: {
        config: '.jscsrc',
        verbose: true
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
        options: {
          exclude: ['/angular/','/jquery/']
        },
      },
      test: {
        "overrides": {
          "blackbaud-skyux": {
            "dependencies": {
              "angular": "^1.6.4"
            },
            "main": [
              "dist/js/sky.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        devDependencies: true,
        src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
        fileTypes:{
          js: {
            block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
              detect: {
                js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
              },
              replace: {
                js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
              }
            }
          }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
        ],
        patterns: {
          js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    ngtemplates: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          module: 'bidrAdminApp',
          htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
          usemin: 'scripts/scripts.js'
        },
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        src: 'views/**/*.html',
        dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js'
      }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    googlefonts: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          fontPath: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/',
          cssFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts.css',
          httpPath: 'fonts/',
          fonts: [{
            family: 'Open Sans',
            styles: [
              300,400,600,700,'400italic'
            ]
          },{
            family: 'Oswald',
            styles: [
              300,400,700
            ]
          }]
        }
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt,json}',
            '*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
            'messages/**/{,*/}*.*',
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts',
          src: [
            'blackbaud-skyux/dist/css/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    sass: {
      dev:{
        options: {
          style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.scss',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },

    autoprefixer: {
      dev: {
        files:{
          '.tmp/styles/app.css':'.tmp/styles/app.css'
        }
      },
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },

    aws: grunt.file.readJSON('aws-keys.json'), // Read the file

    aws_s3: {
      options: {
        accessKeyId: '<%= aws.AWSAccessKeyId %>', // Use the variables
        secretAccessKey: '<%= aws.AWSSecretKey %>', // You can also use env variables
        region: 'us-east-1',
        uploadConcurrency: 5, // 5 simultaneous uploads
        downloadConcurrency: 5 // 5 simultaneous downloads
      },
      production: {
        options: {
          bucket: 'admin.bidr.co',
          access: 'public-read'
        },
        files: [
          {expand: true, cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>', src: ['**'], dest: '/'},
        ]
      },
      staging: {
        options: {
          bucket: 'staging.admin.bidr.co',
          access: 'public-read'
        },
        files: [
          {expand: true, cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>', src: ['**'], dest: '/'},
        ]
      },
      clean_production: {
        options: {
          bucket: 'admin.bidr.co',
          debug: true // Doesn't actually delete but shows log
        },
        files: [
          {dest: './', exclude: "**/*copy*", flipExclude: true, action: 'delete'}, // will delete everything that has copy in the name
        ]
      }
    },

    realFavicon: {
        favicons: {
            src: 'app/favicon_master.png',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            options: {
                iconsPath: '/',
                html: [ '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html' ],
                design: {
                    ios: {
                        pictureAspect: 'backgroundAndMargin',
                        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                        margin: '35%',
                        assets: {
                            ios6AndPriorIcons: false,
                            ios7AndLaterIcons: false,
                            precomposedIcons: false,
                            declareOnlyDefaultIcon: true
                        }
                    },
                    desktopBrowser: {},
                    windows: {
                        pictureAspect: 'noChange',
                        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                        onConflict: 'override',
                        assets: {
                            windows80Ie10Tile: false,
                            windows10Ie11EdgeTiles: {
                                small: false,
                                medium: true,
                                big: false,
                                rectangle: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    androidChrome: {
                        pictureAspect: 'noChange',
                        themeColor: '#1c84c6',
                        manifest: {
                            name: 'Bidr Manager',
                            display: 'standalone',
                            orientation: 'notSet',
                            onConflict: 'override',
                            declared: true
                        },
                        assets: {
                            legacyIcon: false,
                            lowResolutionIcons: false
                        }
                    },
                    safariPinnedTab: {
                        pictureAspect: 'blackAndWhite',
                        threshold: 85.15625,
                        themeColor: '#f8ac59'
                    }
                },
                settings: {
                    scalingAlgorithm: 'NearestNeighbor',
                    errorOnImageTooSmall: false
                }
            }
        }
    },

    notify: {
      deploy: {
        options: {
          message: 'Deploy complete', //required
        }
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'sass:dev',
      'autoprefixer:dev',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:test',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'sass:dev',
    'autoprefixer:dev',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'googlefonts:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('deploy', function(target) {
    grunt.task.run(['build','aws_s3:' + target]);
    grunt.task.run(['notify:deploy']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'newer:jscs',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Where would I place the necessary options in this file to get the connect server to work on https and also livereload to continue working?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your key: xxx and cert: xxx
in
connect: {
options: {
port: 9000,
// Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
hostname: 'localhost',
livereload: 35729,
key: grunt.file.read('xxx'),
cert: grunt.file.read('xxy')
},